# Select where sum less than value

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I am working on a PHP/MySQL timesheet system, and the report I want to create selects all employees who have worked less than the required amount of time between two dates.
The employee's time is stored in hours and minutes (INT), but I am only concerned with the hours.

The employee table looks like:

```
ID | Name
1  | George
2  | Fred
```

The timesheet_entry table:

```
ID | employeeID | hour | date
1  | 1          | 2    | 2013-07-25
2  | 2          | 4    | 2013-07-25
3  | 1          | 3    | 2013-07-25
```

So if I SELECT employees who have worked less than 5 hours (PHP variable hrsLimit) on 2013-07-25, it should return 2 Fred, as George has worked a total of 5 hours on that date.
I have a HTML form so the user can set the variables for the query.

I have tried:

```
SELECT employeeid,
       employeename
FROM   employee
       JOIN timesheet_entry tse
         ON tse.tse_employeeid = employeeid
            AND Sum(tse.hour) < $hrslimit
```

I have not worried about the date yet.

The confusing bit here is that we are joining two tables. Perhaps I should select the hours and put the SUM clause at the end in a WHERE instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group data and then place SUM condition in the HAVING part of the query.

```
select employee.id,
       employee.Name,
       Date,
       sum(`hour`) 
from timesheet_entry
join employee on timesheet_entry.employeeID=employee.ID
group by timesheet_entry.employeeID,date
having sum(`hour`)<$hrslimit
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d26c5/2)

Comment: `sum(hour) as sum_hour ` and then `having sum_hour<$hrslimit` shouldn't have better performance ?

Comment: @jaczes Ok. I think SQL optimizer will make performance the same.

Comment: @valex Thank you, and thank you for a quick response. My example was not the best, all on the same day, but I have now added the GROUP BY date BETWEEN clause http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e454/3 to complete my solution. Thanks again

Comment: i would kiss you if i could valex. Thx